# Cannot get verbose=FALSE working for "joinCountryData2Map"

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rpres

I am using  'R Presentation' from R Studio  to create a slide show for my project. I am using the below code and whatever I do I am not able to get rid of the  output message from the code. I do not want the progress message to be included in my presentation slide.

I have the below portion of code in a different chunk , but that did not help me either.  I cleared cache and tried all stuffs, but could not get  rid of the progress message.

Any idea how to get rid of the output message ?

```
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(subset(world_all, year==year.list[i]),joinCode = "ISO3 ,nameJoinColumn = "country_code" , mapResolution = "coarse",verbose=FALSE)
```

it generates below output message , which I do not want to show in my presentation slide

> 154 codes from your data successfully matched countries in the map 0
>   codes from your data failed to match with a country code in the map 90
>   codes from the map weren't represented in your data

Answer (score 1):

That did not work either. 
Then I went to the source code of that function and found that a "cat" command is being used to  print the messages. So, I muted the cat command output using the below method , and it worked !!

capture.output( 'the whole function' , file='NUL' )

Comment: Can you explain your solution in more detail? Should we copy paste the whole function code inside `capture.output()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; verbose=BOOL controls whether or not the progress messages are printed, not the final message. I'd suggest experimenting with wrapping the call in a call to `suppressMessages`, and seeing what happens.